# Getting started with C# on OS X

Tags: c#, windows, macos

I'd like to create a few simple C# applications and command line utilities to learn more about C#, affordably.  Initially, I tried using Microsoft's free Studio Express in a Windows 8 virtual machine; however, it quickly reported that it could only create apps for the Microsoft app store and failed to **build the simplest examples of an XML file transformer**.

I also found Mono or rather MonoDevelop.   I'm still reading about it.  It seems that the SDK is entangled with the MonoDevelop IDE, and the MonoDevelop installer is actually the Xamarin Studio installer.  Xamarin is a subscription based IDE and inexpensive versions of it appear to be constrained.  Perhaps I need to continue studying; however, I thought I'd ask if anyone has experience getting started with C# on OS X.

Ideally, I'd like the simplest setup.  I prefer using command line compilers, simple code  editors, and build scripts.   Are there Windows and OS X command line compilers for C# applications?  Are there framework libraries that can easily be included that work on both OS X and Windows?

Comment: I would suggest this question is a better fit for Super User, but a simple suggestion: there are multiple versions of Visual Studio Express. If you return to [this page](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx), it's likely you tried VS Express for Windows. There's also a VS Express for Windows **Desktop** that should allow you to build non-Windows Store apps. (In a chaotic world, it's comforting to know that Microsoft remains incredibly terrible at naming products.) I'd run *that* version in a VM, myself.

Comment: Really?  I thought superuser was for non-programming related questions.  Anyhow, you are correct.  I accidentally installed the wrong version.  Being unfamiliar with all, I only noticed on your recommendation.  I clearly recall scrolling through the list, first seeing the web version, the windows version, the desktop version, and then the Team Foundation Server 2013 Express.  I quickly scrolled back and accidentally downloaded the Windows version, though I intended on getting the Windows Desktop version.  I'll give that one a try.  Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, I've never been entirely sure what the consensus is (if there is one) on where questions about *programming tools* should go. Anyrate, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled on using a Windows 8 virtual machine and Visual Studio Express for Windows **Desktop** as Dan J recommended.   For usage similar to mine, simple desktop and command line apps, be careful not to select and install the "V.S.E. for Windows" version.

Answer (score 2):

First, Mono is not an SDK, but a runtime. The specific point of Mono is to be able to, for the most part, run the same IL on other platforms as what runs on .NET for Windows. This means that, barring the slight hiccups in implementation, you could copy a program, run it via "mono program.exe" (via the console) on OS X, and get the same output (I have tested this with Console applications, at least - UI starts to get a little hairier).

In terms of library, the Mono libraries try to mirror the .NET ones so exactly, that the code you write for one is almost completely compatible with the other.

"MonoDevelop" and "Xamarin Studio" are the same thing, simply having applied a name change after a certain version. They are the most well known tools for building in the .NET language family on a non-Windows system (the only tools I even know of), and tend to mirror the shortcuts of Visual Studio well (at least on windows.) Unlike Mono itself, these are an IDE, and do not constrain you any more than VS constrains you into .NET.

The constraints you'll find with free Xamarin apply mostly to their mobile platforms (iOS, Android) and do not affect working with desktop (ie Windows and OS X) applications.